# How can I calculate age in years and days

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How do I calculate the age in years and days i.e **I am `25` year and `100` days old.**

I am getting only year, how can I find days too?

XML View:

```xml
<DatePicker id="BirthDate" placeholder="Select Date ..."
                change="StarthandleChange" width="50%" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
<Button text="click" press="OnPressShowAge" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
```

```js
OnPressShowAge: function(){
     var BirthDate = this.getView().byId("BirthDate").getDateValue();
     var year = BirthDate.getFullYear();
     var today = new Date();
     var age = today.getFullYear() - year;
     alert(age);
}
```

Comment: Which control is _this.getView().byId("BirthDate")_ ?

Comment: I am using datePicker control in sapui5, and this.getView().byId("BirthDate")   is using to get selected date by user

Comment: Can you provide an example with value returned by that control...

Comment: Plz check I have edited question